# How do I change the color of a button?

Tags: c#

The board has 10 row and 10 Column button all Green color the board randomly make 9 red color obstacle. my question is how to changing only green button color to white when hit Go button?  To find pass one by one i use the clink event .....? `

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 99;)
    {

        string btn_name = "btn" + Convert.ToString(i+10);
        var btn_now = this.Controls.Find(btn_name, true)[0];

        btn_name = "btn" + Convert.ToString(i + 1);
        var btn_next = this.Controls.Find(btn_name, true)[0];
        var btn_below = btn_next;



        if (i <= 10 || i == 20 || i == 30 || i == 40 || i == 50 || i == 60 || i == 70 || i == 80 || i == 90)
        {
            btn_name = "btn" + Convert.ToString(i);
            btn_below = this.Controls.Find(btn_name, true)[0];
        }
        if(btn_next.BackColor == Color.GreenYellow) {

            if (i <= 10 || i == 20 || i == 30 || i == 40 || i == 50 || i == 60 || i == 70 || i == 80 || i == 90)
                i+= 1;
            else
                i++;
           btn_now = btn_next;
        }
        else {
            btn_now = btn_next;
            i+=1;                    
        }
        btn_now.BackColor = Color.White;

    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question so as to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you store references to the buttons in an array or list, you would not have to find them.  You could also easily randomize the order (not sure if that is part of the game).

Comment: Your question is not really about changing color of the button is not it? You do `btn_now.BackColor = Color.White;` that is what actually changes the color, so it is about something else. And I have hard time understanding what are you asking (I didn't understand the previous version of same questions).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion i made my question is how to find the short path without passing through the red button everytime i hit go button. btn 1 is the entry and btn 100 is the exit.

Comment: Are you trying to find a path from the top left position to the bottom right without going through any of the red cells?

Answer (score 0):

If this is Windows Forms then it is fairly easy...

This will look for all button controls in the window and change the backcolor to white if it is green. Add it to your Go button event.

```
foreach(Control control in this.Controls)
{
      if(control is Button)
      {
          var btn = control as Button;

          if(btn.BackColor == Color.Green)
          {
             btn.BackColor = Color.White;
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! how to find the path without passing through the red button everytime i hit go button. btn 1 is the entry and btn 100 is the exit.

Comment: @HopeMgd what do you mean by passing through the red button? I think you better post some screenshots of your problem to make it more clear.

Comment: file:///C:/Users/Tesfahun/Desktop/c2.png

Comment: @HopeMgd - You do know that `file:///C:/Users/Tesfahun/Desktop/c2.png` is a file on your local computer that we can't access?